# Using Ext js gridfilters

Tags: extjs

I am trying to implement grid filters into my grid: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.filters.Filters

```
 plugins: 'gridfilters',
```

The weird thing is that it works in my Sencha Fiddle, but in my actual project code, it produces an error. The error happens when I click the header trigger menu, and firebug reports `typeError: g.showMenu()` is not a function.

`showMenu` is property of `gridfilters`, but it is not a function according to the API docs.. Why would it try to call `.showMenu()`?..

Ext version im using is 5.1.1

Comment: Please share your fiddle, so I can easily test my ideas why the problem may occur. My first thought was that [`button.showMenu()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-showMenu) could be internally called by gridfilters, and if the button does not exist (e.g. because you have set [`menuDisabled:false`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-menuDisabled) on the column or use nested columns), it may throw an error.

Comment: @Alexander fiddle is:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=15vs#fiddle/15vs

Comment: What kind of buttons, just any button on the grid?

Comment: Did you added 'Ext.grid.filters.Filters'  in your requires? Also can you post your code what you did?

Comment: I did use requires: ['Ext.grid.filters.Filters'], It's very simple, a grid with plugins: 'gridfilters', But when i click the trigger header, it says showMenu() is not a function. One thing i did discover is that if I set the showMenu to false.. it lets me open up the header trigger menu at least..
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.filters.Filters',{
            pluginId: 'normalFilter',
            showMenu: false,
        })]

Comment: @MohitSaxena Should the require for Ext.util.Filter, on in the store or the grid?

Comment: @PhoonOne - Its not required.  If you post your code we can help. Also try on diff. browsers.